# Cannot return vector by value in cpp

Tags: c++, vector

Having this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Info{
    string word;
    unsigned int i;
};

vector<Info> unique(vector<Info> &vec){
    vector<Info> ret;
    size_t len = vec.size();

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
       int j = 0; 
        for(; j<len; j++){
            if(vec[i].word == vec[j].word){
                vec[i].i++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j>=len){
            Info info{vec[i].word, 0};
            ret.push_back(info);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(){
    vector<Info> words, origs;
    string tmp;

    while(cin >> tmp){
        Info info{tmp, 0};
        words.push_back(info);
    }

    origs=unique(words);

    cout << "number of elements of vector: " << words.size() << ", of which are unique: ";
    for(int i=0; i<origs.size(); i++){
        cout << origs[i].word << " ";
    }
}
```

Should gives unique elements of vector, but if I run it:
foo.cpp:

```
a b c b c
number of elements of vector: 5, of which are unique:
```

No unique, values, that should be obtained by         `origs=unique(words);`, and the result from above should be `a b c`. I am not sure, if `break` breaks only from the `if` block, or also from the inner for loop (which is intented). Can someone help?

Comment: `break` breaks the innermost loop, but the rest of your question is word salad; I can't tell what you're asking (and it seems to have nothing to do with the title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` is used to break from loop not from `if` conditions so yes `break` breaks from the inner loop.
It will be an easier approach to check for the value in ret vector if it exists don't push it.

```
vector<Info> unique(vector<Info> &vec){
    vector<Info> ret;
    size_t len = vec.size();

    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
       boolean exists = false;
       for(int j = 0; j < ret.size(); j++){
         if(vec[i].word == ret[j].word){
           exists = true;
           break;
         }
       }
       if(!exists){
        Info info{vec[i].word, 0};
        ret.push_back(info);
       }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: This works, but why did not worked by original version? The point was that if the inner loop did not finish (because of `break`), then the `j` variable was smaller then `len` (`j`<`len`), and thus the there was duplicate (otherwise no break and create new Info). This is fairly easy, so where was the problem? The `break` as you suggest breaks from innermost loop `for(int j...)`, which still makes sense for my previous version (the condition is **after** the inner most loop), so again, where was bug from the previous version????

Comment: The problem is that you are comparing the element to itself, then no matter what it will always break. look at the example `a b c b c` when you start with `i = 0` and `j = 0` you are comparing `vec[0] == vec[0]` which will be true. and you are doing the same for all other elements that's why the ret vector was empty

Answer (score 0):

`break` will terminate the innermost loop that it is located in, which in this case is your first nested `for` loop.

```
if(j>=len){
            Info info{vec[i].word, 0};
            ret.push_back(info);
        }
```

This block never executes which is probably why your `origs` vector is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

Both `i` and `j` index over the entire vector.

Thus, you compare the first element to itself on the first iteration, the second element to itself on the second iteration, and so on until you have compared every element to itself and found all of them equal to something.
Because of this, nothing is ever added to `ret`.

I think the simplest solution is to compare the elements of `vec` to the elements of `ret` instead.